# Is there a good way to get controller support

Tags: the-witcher

I can't seem to find any native controller support for The Witcher (Enhanced Edition Director's Cut for the PC). Is there any good alternative to emulate controller support for this game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Witcher doesn't have native controller support. In order to use a controller with this game you will need to use an application like XPadder/Pinnacle Game Profiler/Joy2Key to bind your controller axis and buttons to mouse and keyboard actions.

I have never used it but Pinnacle Game Profiler has a section on their website to download [pre-configured profiles for the Witcher](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/pc-controller-support/alpha-gamepad-joystick/xbox-360-ps3-psx-etc/the-witcher) which might provide you with a good place to start if you choose to use Pinnacle Game Profile (which is not free).

Comment: Yes, so what would you recommend?

Comment: From my experience each application behaves different for different games. So if someone got any experience with this game it would be much appreciated. pointing me in the right direction so the tweaking and setup time is mitigated. Thanks @kalina for the help.